# How to make an audio RTP packet without using API along with the transmission and unpacking of the RTP packet

Tags: java, voip, rtp

I'm new in VoIP. I was wondering to create an application that streams audio using Client/Server architecture using RTP. Different APIs are available **but** I need to get understanding at core level. I have studied RFC. Can anybody suggest me how to make an **audio RTP packet** and send it to the server along with the unpacking of the packet in **JAVA**.
Thanking in advance.

Comment: I've implemented it successfully. If anyone wants code from me, don't hesitate contacting me by e-mail. suleman748@gmail.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an empty Java class.

Add members for all the fields in the RTP header.  Use bool for the single bit fields.  For the numerical fields, you need to be mindful of how many bits you need, i.e. use int for SSRC, and timestamp, short for sequence, byte for payload type, etc.  CSRC should be an array (or arrayList or whatever) of ints.  Audio payload should be a byte array.

Packets are just arrays of bytes, so you need a ToBytes() method that will output a packet byte[], and a constructor that takes a byte[] as a parameter.  To send a packet, call ToBytes() and put the result in a UDP packet.

In your ToBytes() method, create a byte array that's 12 bytes, plus an additional 4 bytes for each CSRC, plus however many bytes are in your audio payload.

Single bit values you need to set using the bitwise OR operator.  For example, the Marker bit is the first bit of the second byte, so to set it:

```
if(marker)
{
    bytes[1] = bytes[1] | 0x80;  //0x80 is 1000 0000
}
```

To set the values that are ints or shorts, you'll need to convert the value to a network order (bigendian) byte array and then set it in the buffer using arraycopy.  I'll leave it up to you to find out how to create the network order byte array.

For the constructor that takes a byte[], you'll need to do the above process in reverse.  To check the value of a single bit, use the AND operator, e.g.:

```
marker = bytes[1] & 0x80 == 1;
```

Either in this class or a helper class you'll probably need methods to help set the timestamp based on the packet count and sample rate.  For example, if the payload is G.711, it's 8000 samples/second, which means a packet sent every 20ms with a 160 byte payload, so timestamp will increase by 160 every packet.